# I can't access side variable in my pages from liquid using jekyllrb

Tags: ruby, jekyll, bundle

I'm testing jekyllrb for making a simple block, my variable *side* is *nil* as in my index.md

```
---
layout: default
---
side.time = {{ side.time }} # side.time = 
side.time = {{ side.time | inspect }} # side.time = nil
```

For example, I can't use the `{% for post in side.posts %}` neither in my pages nor my _layouts nor my _includes. Everywhere when I check using the `bundle exec jekyll build --trace` it tells me

> /block/_includes/aside.html line 2): undefined variable side included (Liquid::UndefinedVariable)

The uses of the viable *side* are not working.

I'm using the _config.yml option `strict_variables: true` for debuggin puposes, without it there is no error but I can't use any functionality that include the usage of *side*. It's just *nil*.

I have try to using the `:setlocal nobomb` option on my text editor but my liquid is working with everything else. I have try to use the `excerpt_separator: ""` option on my _config.yml as is says on the documention page, but I wasn't luck with that either.

I have try to search information of an error similiar to this but I coundn't find it. Does someone know what can be the problem?

I'm using `jekyll 4.2.0` and `Bundler version 2.2.6` on kubuntu. I have in my .bashrc

```
export GEM_HOME=$HOME/gems
export PATH=$HOME/gems/bin:$PATH
```

for using ruby gems without the need of sudo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking for `site`, e.g. `{{ site.time }}`.

Comment: A... OK... It worked... Thank you... Sorry! English is not my native language.